# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

VS2010 .NET 4 - This simple app works using my local system.  When I publish it on an IIS 7 web server, I get this error when the application runs this Linq query with a containes function.

```
var results = view_UserInfoRepository.View_UserInfo.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(eMail)).OrderBy(x => x.Email);
```

### Server Error in '/' Application.

> Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: text Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: text
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: text]
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlHelpers.GetStringContainsPattern(String
>   text, Char escape, Boolean& usedEscapeChar) +595083
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.TranslateStringMethod(SqlMethodCall
>   mc) +797
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall mc)
>   +1149    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +2136    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression
>   exp) +11
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
>   select) +48
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1015
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +16
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +430
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
>   +11    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect select) +26
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1015
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +16
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +430
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
>   +11    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect select) +26
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1015
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +16
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +430
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
>   +11    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect select) +26
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1015
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape
>   resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection`1
>   parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) +805
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query,
>   SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) +155
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query) +132
>
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   +34    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +58
>
>   TSM.WebUI.Admin.Controllers.UserAdminController.SearchEMail(String
>   eMail, Int32 page) in C:\Users\Jeff\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TSM\TSM.WebUI.Admin\Controllers\UserAdminController.cs:180
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +151
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +199
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
>   +56    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +267
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassf.b*_c()
>   +20    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +345
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +115
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +42    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_4() +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +43    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8841105    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Answer (score 3):

Well, I *suspect* the problem is that `eMail` is null. The easiest way to check that is to explicitly *set* `eMail` to null before the query on your development box, and see whether that gives the same result. If it does, you need to move on to finding out why it's null in production but not in development.